# Oracle sql Check constraint on date field

Tags: sql, oracle, check-constraints

I want to add a check constraint that compares columnA with year data(format: 2020) to columnB with date data (format: 20200929):

columnA=SUBSTR(columnB,1,4) should be my check constraint.

But need to specify the date format for column B. How can I do that? Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them to be the same, then use:

```
check (columnA = extract(year from columnb))
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a *virtual column*, which will always be consistent!

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD (columnA AS (extract(year from columnB)));
```